# How to add method to a class and where to use "self" in python

Tags: python, class, methods, initialization, self

I'm new to python language and I'm trying to understand the `self` concept.

I have defined the following two methods,  and I am wondering what changes will have to be made in the code to include them in a class and where `self` would be used.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
# This function returns the animCurves connected to particular node 

def animCurveNode():

    animCurveName = []
    mySel = cmds.ls(sl = True)
    filePath = "D:\sdk.txt"
    attrName = "l_eyeBrow_Sliders.eyeBrow_start_updn"
    for each in mySel:
        list = cmds.listConnections(each, d = False,s = True)
        animCurveName.extend(list)

    return animCurveName

# This function return the animCurves and the name of the atribute to connect as the first memebr in the list

def attrAnimCurve():
    attrName = "l_eyeBrow_Sliders.eyeBrow_start_updn"
    animCurveNames = animCurveNode()
    animCurveNames.insert(0,attrName)
    return animCurveNames
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a class here? It's quite important to know what to use the `self` for.

Answer (score 0):

`self` is conventionally the first argument of class methods (functions bound to a class instance). `self` is used as a [reference to the object instance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) in question, and is thus used to read and write that instance's attributes.

This explicit passing of the object reference also allows for setting methods outside of the class definition:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
  def get(self): return self.data

foo = Foo([1,2,3])
Foo.get_data_as_set = lambda self: set(self.data)
print foo.get()
print Foo.get_data_as_set(foo)
```

The above prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have are not methods. They're not in any class. See the simplest example below:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


class MyClass:

    # This method returns the animCurves connected to particular node
    def animCurveNode(self):

        animCurveName = []
        mySel = cmds.ls(sl = True)
        filePath = "D:\sdk.txt"
        attrName = "l_eyeBrow_Sliders.eyeBrow_start_updn"
        for each in mySel:
            list = cmds.listConnections(each, d = False,s = True)
            animCurveName.extend(list)

        return animCurveName

    # This method return the animCurves and the name of the atribute to connect as the first memebr in the list
    def attrAnimCurve(self):
        attrName = "l_eyeBrow_Sliders.eyeBrow_start_updn"
        animCurveNames = animCurveNode()
        animCurveNames.insert(0,attrName)
        return animCurveNames
```

However you didn't really specify what you want to use `self` for. For example, what variables should be a part of the objects.

For more reading about `self` take a look at this:

[What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python)

Comment: There's no point in making those functions part of a class if they are not sharing any data between them.

Comment: This is what I tried to express in my answer. The OP should specify why he wants to use a class in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply ...
Im confused with the concept of what variables should be a part of the objects.
for example in my code

```
class MyClass:

    # This method returns the animCurves connected to particular node
    def animCurveNode(self):

        animCurveName = []
        mySel = cmds.ls(sl = True)
```

or should it be

```
class MyClass:

    # This method returns the animCurves connected to particular node
    def animCurveNode(self):

        self.animCurveName = []
        self.mySel = cmds.ls(sl = True)
```